# Best performance between two examples

Tags: java

`PerformanceTest1`:

```
public class PerformanceTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean i = false;

            if (i == false)
                i = true;
            System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

`PerformanceTest2`:

```
public class PerformanceTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean i = false;

            i = true;
            System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

I've been asking myself about these two possibilities, what would give the best performance. I don't know if the fact of checking `if (i == false)` (at `PerformanceTest1`) every time `while(true)` loop is executed would give a worse performance than just setting `i = true` every time the `while(true)` loop  is executed.

Q: So, `PerformanceTest1` or `PerformanceTest2` would give a best performance? Why?

EDIT:

So, based on the answers, I suppose that the performance of the code below would be the same too?

```
public class PerformanceTest1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Point i;

                if (i == null)
                    i = new Point();

        }
    }


    public class PerformanceTest2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Point i;

                i = new Point();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Both would be equivalent after the JIT compiler runs

Comment: If you are in a situation when you have to care about which one of these is more performant, something is probably wrong.

Comment: The performance of assignment is irrelevant since `System.out.println` would take 99.(9)% of actual running time.

Comment: You're trying the measure the performance of an infinite loop?

Comment: Re: your edit: I would suspect that the JIT compiler would still optimize the contents of both loops away because the assignments don't have any discernible side effects elsewhere in the program. You might get more informative answers if you show more useful code.

Comment: This title is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [branch predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) would just ignore the path which is executing the `if` inside the `while` after few iterations so there will be no difference, as the condition will be always `false`.

The CPU will keep its execution as assuming that the `if` is not taken and by getting a 100% prediction hit. So there will be no rollback and the two becomes basically equivalent.

Just as a side note, there's no need to have `i == false`, `!i` is enough.

Comment: I also thought about the branch predictor, but I actually think that the JVM would get rid of the if-test altogether as the i in this case will always be false. However, I'm not sure if that is the case, I just read about branch prediction a few weeks ago. Very interesting concept!

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference in terms of performance between the two methods.

The first if-test will only be executed once. This is because the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) will not perform the test after a few times as i will always be true. I'm no expert on the JVM and runtime, but you might even expect the if-test to only run once.

Answer (score -1):

They both will have the same performance, but I believe that the PerformanceTest1 *might* take up more performance, since you are doing an extra operation. it takes less performance to simply assign a value to a boolean variable, than checking if it equals to false first

Comment: Well, only if you reevaluate the `if` every iteration, and the JIT compiler *should* (and almost certainly *will*) optimize that away